# Add header to Swagger UI curl command

Tags: spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui

The `curl` command generated by Swagger UI for my service is as follows:

`curl -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" "http://localhost:8080/foo/402215"`

How can I add an extra header to the command so I get the following:

`curl -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" --header "Content-type: application/json" "http://localhost:8080/foo/402215"`

My controller looks something like:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/",
    consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE},
    produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE}
)
public class BlobController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public Blob foo(@RequestBody String id) {
        return new Blob();
    }
}
```

I'm using Spring Boot and SpringFox.

Comment: This should be added automatically by the UI.  See here as an example:

http://petstore.swagger.io/#!/pet/addPet

Post your swagger description and it'll be easy to debug.

Comment: Yes, I thought it should be. I have a 'Response Content Type' drop down but what is selected does not get added to the curl command.

Comment: Please post your swagger json

Comment: I am in the same boat. Did you figure out how you added the new headers?

Comment: I removed ```produces``` and ```consumes``` from ```@RequestMapping``` on the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Accept and Content-type parameters should be generated automatically. If you want to have headers with dynamic values you could add the `@HeaderParam` annotation to your method signature:

```
public Blob foo(@RequestBody String id, @HeaderParam(value= "some_header") String someHeader) {
    return new Blob();
}
```

Swagger would then show that header parameter together with other path & query parameters.

Answer (score -1):

To Add a custom header, you can amend the swagger index.html file and add a line in like this:

`swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations.add("Content-Type", new SwaggerClient.ApiKeyAuthorization("Content-Type", "application/json", "header"));`

See here: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui#custom-header-parameters---for-basic-auth-etc